# Loading JSON on UITableView w/ Monotouch

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.iOS to return a JSON and attempt to place it on a UITableView, however I am overriding what `ToString()` is in a Datum class in the Instagram client class, I want to be able to fix this so I can load more than just their names...

Here is the **Instagram Client** that turns the JSON into class objects:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public object attribution { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object location { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public Likes likes { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public List<object> users_in_photo { get; set; }
    public Caption caption { get; set; }
    public bool user_has_liked { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Videos videos { get; set; }


             // This is the Overridden method I want to get rid of

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            return "User is null";
        }
        return user.full_name;
    }
}

public class Videos
{
    public LowResolution2 low_resolution { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution2 standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Caption
{
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public LowResolution low_resolution { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Likes
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public string next_url { get; set; }
    public string next_max_id { get; set; }
}
```

**Main View Controller**

This is how I am returning the JSON

```
var request = new RestRequest { RootElement = "data", Resource = "/users/self/feed" };
            request.AddParameter ("access_token", instagramAccessToken);

            var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");
            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (response.Content);
                table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    table.Source = new TableSource<Datum>(rootObject.data);
                    table.ReloadData ();
                });
            }
        );
```

**TableSource Class**

```
            public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource ()
    {
        Data = new List<T> ();
    }

    public TableSource(List<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return Data.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (OnRowSelected != null) {
            OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
        }
    }

    public class RowSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UITableView tableView { get; set; }
        public NSIndexPath indexPath { get; set; }

        public RowSelectedEventArgs(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) : base()
        { 
            this.tableView = tableView;
            this.indexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> OnRowSelected;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        if (tableView.ContentSize.Height - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height <= tableView.ContentOffset.Y) {
            // this is the last row in the last section
            Console.WriteLine ("~~~Bottom~~~");
        }

        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        // Edited Text 
        cell.TextLabel.Text = Data[indexPath.Row].ToString ();

        return cell;
    }
```

I didn't really have a concrete method of displaying the JSON on the Table, so I would be pretty open to radical change.

Answer (score 0):

In your GetCell method you can access any property of your data.  You probably want to create a custom UITableViewCell if you want to display more than two lines of data.

```
var item = Data[indexPath.Row];
cell.TextLabel.Text = item.User.username + " (" + item.User.full_name + ")";
cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "Created at: " + item.created_time;
```

Comment: The problem with that is that my Data list defined in my table source is having <T> as the object type not datum so I cannot do your suggestion.

Comment: I also want to keep it as public List<T> Data instead of public List<Datum> Data because I want to be able to give different class objects to the source

Comment: Define an Interface with a GetCell() method that your Client classes must implement.  Constrain your Source<T> to that interface.  Then your Source can just call T.GetCell() and each Client class can be responsible for building it's own cell.

Comment: I dont understand can you please show an example with code :)

Comment: I would really suggest you stop using a generic source class.  It sounds like it is creating more problems for you than it is solving.

Comment: What do you mean what would I use besides for the generic source class?

Comment: Create a custom source for each table instead of trying to use Source<T>

Comment: Ok but what if I want the 3 different cells onto the same tableview

Comment: Modify GetCell to return the appropriate type of cell based on whatever your criteria are.